# Winter Bash site header and footer shows 2018 when JS is disabled

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, winter-bash, winter-bash-2019

The header on the Winter Bash knitting editor and the site footer shows 2018 when JavaScript is disabled, as the image between the `<noscript>` tags isn't updated to 2019.

**Header:**

```
<noscript>&lt;img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/header-large-main.png?v=2390b8b5f07d" /&gt;</noscript>
```

Specifically, this image – https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/header-large-main.png?v=2390b8b5f07d.

**Footer:**

```
<noscript>&lt;img src="https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/footer.png?v=c3c9a74a3dae" /&gt;</noscript>
```

Specifically, this image – https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/footer.png?v=c3c9a74a3dae.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `<noscript>` fallback header and footer images have been updated to show the correct year.

Comment: Hi again, I’m still seeing 2018 on the [site footer](https://cdn.sstatic.net/Winterbash/img/footer.png?v=c3c9a74a3dae); the header’s fixed. Could you take a look?